# Can't get rid of AbstractController::DoubleRenderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller

I'm getting a double render error that I cannot get rid of in the update method of my model.

Here's the code for the controller

```
class Admin::CmsHappeningNowFeatureController < ApplicationController

    def index
        # Various model data retrieval...

        render 'admin/cms/hn_features/index', layout: 'admin_cms'
    end

    # Works fine
    def edit
        @feature = CmsHappeningNowFeature.find_by_id(params[:id])
        render 'admin/cms/hn_features/feature', layout: 'admin_cms'
    end

    # Throws a AbstractController::DoubleRenderError upon submission
    def update
        @feature = CmsHappeningNowFeature.find_by_id(params[:id])
        @feature.attributes = params[:cms_happening_now_feature]
        if @feature.save
            redirect_to(:action => index, :notice => "Successfully updated feature.") and return
        end 
        render 'admin/cms/hn_features/feature', layout: 'admin_cms'
    end

    # ... rest of the class
end
```

When redirecting to another controller, the issue disappears. It seems that redirecting to the same controller makes rails execute the method without actually sending a redirect. By looking at the log, when submitting the update form, `update` gets called, then `index` gets called, `render` from index is executed and **then** the redirect is issued and fails.

What am I missing? What's the workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, the real cause is that in

```
redirect_to(:action => index, :notice => "Successfully updated feature.") and return
#                      ^^^^^ This calls the index method
```

you call the `index` method which will then render first. The `redirect_to` call will then get the result of that function back (which will be whatever the `render`call in `index` returns). and renders the second time

What you really want to write is this:

```
redirect_to(:action => :index, :notice => "Successfully updated feature.") and return
```

where you set `:action` to a symbol, i.e. index which represents the action but does not directly call it.

Comment: Ha! Thanks! I did not catch the fact that `:action => index` was actually calling `index` and returning the result to `:action`

Answer (score 1):

you have

```
if @feature.save
   redirect_to(:action => index, :notice => "Successfully updated feature.") and return
end
```

Which redirects to index then redirects again from index which gets the error thrown

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
if @feature.save
   index
   flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated feature." 
   return
end
```

Comment: This works, however, the url does not get updated and if the user hits refresh, the form gets resubmitted which is a big drawback... that is the whole advantage of using redirect. The only way I've managed to fix this is by specifying a path such as `redirect_to admin_cms_hn_feature_index_path, :notice => "Successfully updated feature." and return`

Comment: I don't know why a redirect_to command would actually execute the action `index` before redirecting to it. This is confusing and not what you would expect from the command.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this problem, however it was not involving any redirect to or multiple renders in controller.  We had an action that triggers an email directly, no backend queue to put it on.  This uses ActionMailer gem which I believe does a render on the .haml or other template to generate the html for the email.  We then after sending email were using an
render update call at end

Can this cause this error?  Rails think ActionMailer's render of email template is a regular render?  Its just a guess, not sure what else it could be.....also I can't reproduce it 100% but doesn't look like concurrency thing as in logs I only see one call to controller.

Any ideas welcome, thank you.

Comment: FYI I discovered the reason for this.  It appears if rabl is setup in certain way with a child node and its expecting one item but gets multiple this can happen.  So its kind of like a child included rabl will be rendered twice unexpectingly and this happens. I was surprised by this, thought the json would have just had double/extra data.